# How to make a Docker container talk to geth.ipc on local host

Tags: go-ethereum, web3.py, python, docker, ipc

```
from web3 import Web3

web3 = Web3(Web3.IPCProvider("/Ethereum/geth.ipc"))
print(f'IPC connected: {web3.isConnected()}')  # want to return True
```

I have the above script Dockerized and I'm trying to connect to `geth.ipc` on local host and I can't seem to connect to it.

Here is how I run Docker:

```
docker run --mount type=bind,source=$HOME/Library/Ethereum,target=/Ethereum container1
```

I've verified that `geth.ipc` exists in `/Ethereum` directory but cannot seem to connect to it. Is there a way to do it?

The question might be related to [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/52574/how-to-connect-to-ethereum-node-geth-via-ipc-from-outside-of-docker-container) and here is my original question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52715141/how-to-make-a-docker-container-talk-to-geth-on-local-host

Comment: If anyone’s interested, I submitted an issue at geth repo: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/17907

Answer (score 2):

If you mount the folder containing the IPC file rather than the file directly it will work.

Comment: Can permission cause a problem ? I.e. will the user that is running docker instance, have access to socket created by user on localhost ?

Comment: If you mount it via -v flag then there shouldn't be any permission issues.

Answer (score 1):

Use `host.docker.internal`

This works on Docker for Mac and Docker for Windows.

If you're on Linux, things get more complex. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach

Comment: This approach doesn't seem to work. I'll submit an issue with geth

Answer (score 0):

geth.ipc represent an "Unix Domain Socket".

This article has steps to expose suck a socket to docker container.

https://www.jujens.eu/posts/en/2017/Feb/15/docker-unix-socket/